# Different db connection for models using hasManyThrough relationship in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, query-builder

I am trying to use the hasManyThrough relationship in laravel 5.1 but the sql query is not using the appropriate prefix defined in each connection for each model used.
I have 3 models 2 of which use the same connection and one of them uses a different one. The only difference between the connections is the prefix the database is the same.

- Model A has connection A which uses prefix A_
- Model B has connection B which uses prefix B_
- Model C has connection B which uses prefix B_

The relationship:

Inside Model B:

```
public function relationshipWithA()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(A::class, C::class, 'Cid', 'Aid');
}
```

The final query logic is correct but instead of using the B_ prefix for the joined tables its using the A_ prefix for all the tables in the query.

Is this a bug/limitation of laravel? Is there a solution to this or I will have to do manual join to achieve what I want?

Comment: laravel models will not work with different connections for relationships because eloquent uses SQL joins behind the scenes and that won't be possible with more than one DB connection

Answer (score 5):

Other relationship types work with multiple database connections:

```
public function foos()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Foo::class, 'other_db.foos');
}
```

But `hasManyThrough` does not have the `$table` parameter in its signature, so the same solution is not applicable.

**However,**

You can make an imperfect workaround like this:

```
public function bars()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Bar::class, 'other_db.bars');
}

public function foos()
{
    $barIds = $this->bars->pluck('id');
    return Foo::whereIn('bar_id', $barIds);
}
```

It does not offer the exact same functionality (Since it is a different return-type), but fulfills the purpose for more simple things.

If you want, you can also replicate some more of the syntax by doing something like this:

```
protected $appends = [
    'foos',
];

/**
 * @return Foo[]
 */
public function getFoosAttribute()
{
    return $this->foos()->get();
}
```

That way you can still use it in your code like you would most of the time with a regular relationship (Meaning you can use `$this->foos` instead of `$this->foos()->get()`)

Answer (score -1):

Actually, it seems to work fine if you specify the connections inside your model classes via the `$connection` property. I tested it (Laravel 5.5) between a MySQL and SQL connection using a morphMany relationship:

Account Model:

```
class Account extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'sqlsrv';

    public function notifications()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Notification::class, 'notifiable');
    }
}
```

Notification Model:

```
class Notification extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'mysql';

    public function notifiable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Comment: It might work for morphMany but this question is about hasManyThrough which doesn't work.